# Bootstrap 4.6 + CSS, how to bottom align a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I wanna place the back button to the bottom of the page (respecting the 2rem padding on class "tamanho1"). However, I dont know how to do it.

Did some research, most of them suggested to use:

> "align-content: space-between"

tried on "tamanho1" class, but it doesn't work, also tried to add a class `"align-self-end"` on the back link-button but it still doesn't work. Why? =((((

Here is my code:

```css
    <style>
        
.container {
    background-color: white;
}

.container-especial{
    background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185) !important;
}

.tamanho1{
    background-color: white;
    margin-top:2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    align-content: space-between;
}

#nav-Gest {
    background-color: rgba(182, 162, 201, 0.658);
    color: white;
}

.botao-maior {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}


#botao-Gest-outline {
    background-color: rgba(182, 162, 201, 0.658);
}

#botao-Voltar2 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;

}



    </style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Tela inicial</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container container-especial d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 90%; height:800px">
        <div class="container tamanho1 border rounded">
            <div class="row mt-3 mb-5">
                <nav class="navbar border rounded col-12 justify-content-center" id="nav-Gest">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top border" alt=""></a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Escolha a Opção</h2>
                    <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> A </a>
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> B </a>
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> C </a>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row border align-self-end mt-5">
                    <a class="btn " id="botao-Voltar2"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x"></i> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use `align-content` and `justify-content`, the div has to have `display: flex` applied. You actually need `justify-content` because you are trying to align items along horizontal (primary, X) axis.

Applying it has also centered the div with A,B,C (the first snippet). Should that be a problem, you need to make some more adjustments (see the second snippet).

```css
.container {
    background-color: white;
}

.container-especial{
    background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185) !important;
}

.tamanho1{
    background-color: white;
    margin-top:2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#nav-Gest {
    background-color: rgba(182, 162, 201, 0.658);
    color: white;
}

.botao-maior {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}


#botao-Gest-outline {
    background-color: rgba(182, 162, 201, 0.658);
}

#botao-Voltar2 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Tela inicial</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container container-especial d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 90%; height:800px">
        <div class="container tamanho1 border rounded">
            <div class="row mt-3 mb-5">
                <nav class="navbar border rounded col-12 justify-content-center" id="nav-Gest">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top border" alt=""></a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Escolha a Opção</h2>
                    <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> A </a>
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> B </a>
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> C </a>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row border mt-5">
                    <a class="btn " id="botao-Voltar2"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x"></i> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

```css
.container {
    background-color: white;
}

.container-especial{
    background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185) !important;
}

.tamanho1{
    background-color: white;
    margin-top:2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#nav-Gest {
    background-color: rgba(182, 162, 201, 0.658);
    color: white;
}

.botao-maior {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
    text-align: center;
}


#botao-Gest-outline {
    background-color: rgba(182, 162, 201, 0.658);
}

#botao-Voltar2 {
    font-size: 1.3rem;

}

.content-container {
  flex: 1;
   display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start !important;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Tela inicial</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container container-especial d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 90%; height:800px">
        <div class="container tamanho1 border rounded">
            <div class="row mt-3 mb-5">
                <nav class="navbar border rounded col-12 justify-content-center" id="nav-Gest">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top border" alt=""></a>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="row content-container">
                    <h2 class="text-center">Escolha a Opção</h2>
                    <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-column">
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> A </a>
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> B </a>
                        <a class="btn botao-maior" id="botao-Gest-outline"> C </a>
                   </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row border mt-5">
                    <a class="btn " id="botao-Voltar2"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left fa-2x"></i> </a>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

I have also removed the `align-self-end` from the button as it was forcing it to the right side of the screen. It is not really a "bootstrap" solution. Maybe someone with more bootstrap experience will have a better idea.

...just nitpicking - writing code in english makes the life of the people that are trying to help easier.